# Rock Paper Scissors not working properly JS

Tags: javascript, html

I can only seem to get 2 outcomes when player selects rock or scissors. Wont always run on click. Very buggy and slow. Check out the site and the code and let me know what yall think is up. My first script project so it ain't pretty.

Edit: changed num === from 123 to 012 still wont work

https://duskope.github.io/rockpaperscissors/

https://github.com/Duskope/rockpaperscissors/blob/main/index.js

```js
let resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result')

let userChoice
let compChoice
let result

document.getElementById('rock').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userChoice = 'rock'
  genCompChoice()
  getResult()

})
document.getElementById('paper').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userChoice = 'paper'
  genCompChoice()
  getResult()
})
document.getElementById('scissors').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userChoice = 'scissors'
  genCompChoice()
  getResult()
})

function genCompChoice() {
  let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

  if (num === 0) {
    compChoice = 'rock'
  }
  if (num === 1) {
    compChoice = 'paper'
  }
  if (num === 2) {
    compChoice === 'scissors'
  }
}

function getResult() {
  if (userChoice === compChoice) {
    result = 'Draw. You both suck.'
  }
  if (userChoice === 'rock' && compChoice === 'paper') {
    result = 'Paper beats rock. You lose.'
  }
  if (userChoice === 'rock' && compChoice === 'scissors') {
    result = 'Rock beats scissors. You win.'
  }
  if (userChoice === 'paper' && compChoice === 'rock') {
    result === 'Paper beats rock. You win.'
  }
  if (userChoice === 'paper' && compChoice === 'scissors') {
    result = 'Scissors beats paper patrick. You lost nerd.'
  }
  if (userChoice === 'scissors' && compChoice === 'rock') {
    result = 'Rock beats scissors. Are you even trying?'
  }
  if (userChoice === 'scissors' && compChoice === 'paper') {
    result = 'Scissors beats paper. You win.'
  }
  resultDisplay.innerHTML = result
}
```

```html
<div class="maingrid" id="title">
  <h1 class="mainhead">Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
</div>
<div class="maingrid" id="desc">
  <h2>Choose your weapon</h2>
</div>
<div class="maingrid" id="weaponsgrid">
  <div class="weapons" id="rock">
    <p class="weaponlabel">Rock</p><img src="/rockpaperscissors/images/bbaeb9dc-f31f-498b-8183-2073e1361f49-1656364575448.jpg" alt="Rock" class="weaponimg">
  </div>
  <div class="weapons" id="paper">
    <p class="weaponlabel">Paper</p><img src="/rockpaperscissors/images/paper.png" alt="Paper" class="weaponimg">
  </div>
  <div class="weapons" id="scissors">
    <p class="weaponlabel">Scissors</p><img src="images/scissors.jpeg" alt="Scissors" class="weaponimg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="maingrid" id="resultDisplay">
  <span id="result"></span>
</div>
<div class="maingrid" id="footer">from Daddy Duskope</div>
```

Comment: seems to work OK to me. While it doesn't always update on click, that will just be because the result is the same so you're replacing some text with the exact same thing.

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` will never return 3, so you won't get the "scissors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
function genCompChoice() {
  let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  if (num === 1) {
    compChoice = 'rock'
  }
  if (num === 2) {
    compChoice = 'paper'
  }
  if (num === 3) {
    compChoice === 'scissors'
  }
}
```

is a problem. `Math.random` generates a random number between 0 and 1 (exclusive), so `Math.random() * 3` is between 0 and 3 (exclusive), so `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` is an integer between 0 and 2 (inclusive).

If that number is 0, it doesn't enter into any of the branches in `genCompChoice`, and `compChoice` remains at its previous value.

If the number is 1 or 2, either `rock` or `paper` will be assigned. The number will never be 3.

So you need

```
function genCompChoice() {
  const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  if (num === 0) {
    compChoice = 'rock'
  }
  if (num === 1) {
    compChoice = 'paper'
  }
  if (num === 2) {
    compChoice = 'scissors'
  }
}
```

(Make sure to assign with `compChoice = 'scissors'` - don't compare with `===`)

Comment: just tried this, still wont generate scissors

Comment: Use `compChoice = 'scissors'` (not `compChoice === 'scissors'`)